# the UICollectionView cell is centered why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had a problem with the collectionView.
In fact, I had this algorithm :
- the first cell's width is screen_width/2
- the second cell's width is : screen_width
- the third cell's width is screen_width/2
- the fourth cell's width is : screen_width.

and so on.

This is my code in the method

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath:

    userStory.typePhotoStory = ( (indexPath.row + 1) % 3) == 0 ? @"landscape" : ((indexPath.row + 1) % 3) == 1 ? @"portrait": @"landscape";
    if ([userStory.typePhotoStory isEqualToString:@"portrait"]) {
        cellSizeFinalWidth = cellSize / 2 ;
        cellSizeFinalHeight = cellSizeFinalWidth + 20 ;
    } else {
        cellSizeFinalWidth = cellSize + padding ;
        cellSizeFinalHeight = cellSize / 2 + 20 ;
    }
}
```

But I see that, The first and the third cell are placed in the center of the screen , not started from the left.
Please help me on this issue?

Comment: show your code, constraints and the expected vs. actual outcome.

Comment: @luk2302 i added the code . 
if  you try this code , you will have the first /third cell at center.
I want that the first cell  must be in the left not in the center of the screen

Comment: You have to use a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` because that's the basic behavior.

Comment: @MohamedSGHBS It is the default behaviour of collectionview i.e. if your cell is not fitted in width then it takes full width.

Comment: can you please help me to use another  custom flowlayout ?

Comment: Use https://github.com/KelvinJin/AnimatedCollectionViewLayout for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use this code,

1. **Create a new file and paste this below code for custom layout.**

   ```
   import UIKit

   protocol NewLayoutDelegate: class {
       func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, SizeOfCellAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGSize
   }


   class NewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

       weak var delegate : NewLayoutDelegate?

       fileprivate var numberOfColumns = 1
       fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 6
       fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()


       fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

       fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
           guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
               return 0
           }
           let insets = collectionView.contentInset
           return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
       }

       override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
           return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
       }

       override func prepare() {
           super.prepare()

           guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
               return
           }

           let xOffset : CGFloat = 0
           let column = 0
           var yOffset = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)

           for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

               let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
               let aSize = delegate?.collectionView(collectionView, SizeOfCellAtIndexPath: indexPath)
               let height = cellPadding * 2 + (aSize?.height)!
               let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset[column], width: (aSize?.width)!, height: height)
               let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

               let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
               attributes.frame = insetFrame
               cache.append(attributes)

               contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
               yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height


           }
       }

       override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

           var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

           for attributes in cache {
               if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                   visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
               }
           }
           return visibleLayoutAttributes
       }

       override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
           return cache[indexPath.item]
       }

   }
   ```
2. **In your controller file**

   ```
   import UIKit

   class NewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   }

   class NewViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, NewLayoutDelegate {

       @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = NewFlowLayout()

           if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? NewFlowLayout {
               layout.delegate = self
           }

       }

       // Do size logic here
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, SizeOfCellAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

           let insets = collectionView.contentInset

           if indexPath.item % 2 == 0 {
               return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width - (insets.left + insets.right))/2,
                             height: 60)
           }

           return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width - (insets.left + insets.right),
                         height: 60)
       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return 10
       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewCell

           return cell
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Output**

[image]

Comment: Hello,
please can you translate it to Objective c ? i'm not very familiar with swift :)

Comment: please can you translate me this to objective c :
 var yOffset = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)

Comment: @MohamedSGHBS try this -> `NSArray *yOffset  = [1];` , as **numberOfColumns** is always be 1 here, so keep directly it in the array. Hope it works

Comment: @MohamedSGHBS I hadn't noticed tag on your post else I wrote this code in objc. For now, if you facing issue here then write your own code by talking ref from (here)[https://octodev.net/custom-collectionviewlayout/]. Here explanation is given in both obj-c and swift & everything explained very good. Still you need any help then you can ask.